# How to properly decompress a file with GIO?

Tags: compression, zlib, glib, gio

GIO provides a Zlib [converter to decompress](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GZlibDecompressor.html#g-zlib-decompressor-new) a file. The [decompression function](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GConverter.html#g-converter-convert) takes the output buffer size in parameter.

Is it possible to know the size this buffer should have before decompressing the file ? If not, what is the convention about this size ? Is it a frequently used ratio between compressed and decompressed size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation you linked to says, "It is to be called multiple times in a loop, and each time it will do some work, i.e. producing some output (in outbuf ) or consuming some input (from inbuf ) or both."

In other words, you're not supposed to have to decompress the entire file in one function call.  You should choose a buffer size that works for you and just read into it repeatedly until the stream has no more data.

> Is it possible to know the size this buffer should have before decompressing the file ?

It's not possible to know the decompressed size of the buffer ahead of time unless you have stored that information separately (neither zlib nor GIO does it for you).

> If not, what is the convention about this size ? Is it a frequently used ratio between compressed and decompressed size ?

There is none.  For extremely repetitive data a compressed bytes can decompress to a huge number of bytes (gzip will compress a gigabyte of NULL bytes compresses to 1020 bytes here), and for uncompressible data the "compressed" data could actually be a bit larger than the uncompressed data (see the compressBound function in zlib).